# Display image based on combobox value on same page

Tags: javascript

How to display a image depends on the value selected in the combo box and image is to display in the same page near to the combo box...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: like this http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

Comment: Use JavaScript. That will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `onchange` with `select` in html. Using `Javascript` you can get it done. An example would be like below. Just check the value selected in javascript function and decide which image to be displayed. I have compared the values but you can even have a image name itself.

```
<select name="number" id="course" style="width:158px;" onchange="getImage(this)">
  <option value="none">----Select ----</option>
  <option >1</option>
  <option >2</option>  
</select>
<img id="imgt" src="default.jpg" width="300" height="300"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getImage(v) {
        var num = v.value;
        alert(num);
        if(num==1) {
            document.getElementById("imgt").setAttribute("src","image1.jpg");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("imgt").setAttribute("src","image2jpg");    
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank u for ur valuable help... thanks a lot sir because its really working...